# I can't access vagrant from url

Tags: vagrant, ip, virtualbox

I'm new on vagrant and vm - sorry for that.

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
 config.vm.synced_folder "/home/user/test/public", "/var/www/"
end
```

vagrant up and vagrant ssh are fine but 192.168.33.10 doesn't open in my browser.

What can I do?

Comment: do you have a web server running on your VM (nginx, apache) ?

Comment: yes i installed apache2

Comment: Do you have another vagrant machine running? Did you check apache logs in vagrant machine? what happens when you do `telnet 192.168.33.10 80`?

Comment: other vagrant machine are power off. telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Is firewall turned on? Check if port 80 is allowed? Can you do `curl localhost` inside vm?

Answer (score 1):

curl localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL / was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: is `curl localhost` running from the VM ? if so it means your web server has nothing to display

Answer (score 1):

It looks like firewall issue

do `sudo iptables -S | grep 80`

You should see `ACCEPT` at end of line with `80` in it.

If you don't see any output with `80` in it, try following solution.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Go through 
[ubuntu trusty ufw config](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-configure-ufw-firewall-on-ubuntu-14-04)  and [iptables tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)